# Links in ToC missing targets by a few pages

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I have a very long article class document (~300p).  The links in the ToC often miss the targets in the document by a few pages.  The problem goes away when I shorten the document so I can't make a *minimal* working example.  However, the behavior is seen by clicking the link to "Part I" in the ToC [here](https://vixra.org/pdf/2206.0152v1.pdf), if my description is insufficient.  It jumps to page 28 when it should jump to page 30.  Due to my suspicion that the problem is due to a package conflict, I am including my entire header without removing what seems (to me) to be unrelated.

If there is some way I can add specific target tags for the links in the ToC other than the section headings themselves, that would probably be the simplest thing.  Thanks!

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,notitlepage]{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage[left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang,font=singlespacing,font=large]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}    
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\Large \underline{\underline{$\,\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$Contents$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$}}\hfill\newline}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{1ex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newif\iffirst\firsttrue %

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{762style}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[OC]{\textsc{FAKE NAME}}
    \fancyhead[EC]{\textsc{FAKE TITLE}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{titletoc}

%%%%%%  NO SECTION NUMBERS IN TOC  %%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\let\latexl@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@section{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\let\latexl@subsection\l@subsection
\def\l@subsection#1#2{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@subsection{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\makeatother
  
\title{FAKE TITLE}
\author{FAKE NAME}
\begin{document}
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \maketitle
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \begin{abstract}
             FAKE TEXT
        \end{abstract}
    \end{minipage}
    
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\raggedbottom
\newpage

\newgeometry{left=2in,right=2in,top=1.4in,bottom=1.4in}
\large{

\tableofcontents

\restoregeometry
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{762style}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}\normalsize
```

This is how I typeset the "Part I" heading that I'm using as an example.

```
\section*{\underline{Part I: The Modified Cosmological Model}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\underline{Part I: The Modified Cosmological Model}}
```

Following Ulrike's helpful comment, I see it is only these unnumbered sections which have the problem.  Here is a (numbered) section that is linked accurately.

```
\section{The $\boldsymbol{\hat M^3}$ Operator and its Equation}\label{sec:M3}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me you should be using **both** `titletoc` and `tocloft` (I don't know if they actually conflict, but they overlap significantly in purpose). Also, I think `hyperref` should be loaded after either anyway. Do you actually use `titletoc` for anything? The preamble you included doesn't seem to use it. If so, try removing `\usepackage{titletoc}` and see what happens.

Comment: I commented it out.  It threw a compiler error that went away on recompile.  The document looks the same and the ToC linking is still messed up, unfortunately.  Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: it is always possible to create a minimal example. Only sometimes it is more work to figure out what one can remove and still recreate the problem.  Apart from this: as you have a problem with the Part it would be a good to show at least how you typeset that and add it to the toc.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. But quite likely `\pagenumbering{gobble}` is among the possible causes: ***never*** use it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added that section header at the bottom of my post.  Thank you so much for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see it is only these unnumbered ```\section*``` giving a problem.  All the ```\section``` sections link properly.

Comment: The problem also happens with Part II.  The heading "Appendices" in the TOC doesn't appear in the main text but is paged one page earlier than the first appendix; the formatting in the TOC looks similar to that for Part.  Finally, Part IV begins very near the bottom of a page (the link works correctly).  So I'd look at how `\part` is treated (and maybe add "needspace" to avoid placement like that of Part IV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the hyperref documentation writes, titlesec is only partly supported and unnumbered sections miss anchors if this package is used. You can add an anchor manually with `\phantomsection`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{abc}
abc\newpage 


\section*{\phantomsection\underline{Part I: The Modified Cosmological Model}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\underline{Part I: The Modified Cosmological Model}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome!  It works perfectly.   Thank you.

Comment: It worked for all my "Parts" but the APPENDICES in the ToC is still linked to the last secion rather than the first appendix.  Any suggestions?  ```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\underline{APPENDICES}}

\newpage
\appendix


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\hypertarget{app:A}{}
\section*{Appendix A: The Origin of $\boldsymbol{\hat M^3}$} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{A: The Origin of $\boldsymbol{\hat M^3}$}
\thispagestyle{plain}```

Comment: plant a \phantomsection at the right place.

Comment: If I plant it before \addcontentsline, it almost works but messes up the links to the actual appendices.

Comment: I got it.  I \phantomsection-ed all of them it's all good.  Thank you!